# How create a fullscreen view of a group of controls, that belongs to a tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like to know what is the correct way to create a fullscreen view of a tabpage control. This page has other controls, and that controls has various events that are subscribed. I was trying creating a new fullscreen form and copy all controls of the tabs to that form, but with this approach i need to resubscribe every control to the corresponding handler. If i only add the references the subscription remains but when the fullscreen form is close also the referenced copied controls are lost.

Comment: There's a chance this could help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419356/how-do-you-modify-a-control-that-has-been-re-parented-to-a-tabpage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be elegantly done by Winforms' support for reparenting a control.  You could move it to a temporary form that's displayed full-screen.  All the normal event handlers still work as usual.  Here's a sample implementation, it works for any control:

```
    public static void ShowFullScreen(Control ctl) {
        // Setup host form to be full screen
        var host = new Form();
        host.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        host.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        host.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        // Save properties of control
        var loc = ctl.Location;
        var dock = ctl.Dock;
        var parent = ctl.Parent;
        var form = parent;
        while (!(form is Form)) form = form.Parent;
        // Move control to host
        ctl.Parent = host;
        ctl.Location = Point.Empty;
        ctl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        // Setup event handler to restore control back to form
        host.FormClosing += delegate {
            ctl.Parent = parent;
            ctl.Dock = dock;
            ctl.Location = loc;
            form.Show();
        };
        // Exit full screen with escape key
        host.KeyPreview = true;
        host.KeyDown += (KeyEventHandler)((s, e) => {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) host.Close();
        });
        // And go full screen
        host.Show();
        form.Hide();
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ShowFullScreen(tabControl1);
    }
```

Comment: thank you Hans, with the tabpage itself doesn't work but with the tabcontrol yes. In order to add other controls that i also need in the fullscreen view, i added a panel and put inside everything that i need, and in the showfullscreen i pass that panel. Now i need to think how can i use all the space available, perhaps the panel has dock fill, all other controls are using his standard size. Other thing is that in the While cycle, is need it check the existence of the parent, if they don't exist then break.

Comment: after a couple of tuning, the fullscreen view was beautiful. i'm going to add you to the list of Collaborators in the credits of my application, XD, thanks again.

Comment: I had some problems with Dock=Fill controls not sizing correctly... classic problem of rendering order.
Added ctl.BringToFront(); before form.Show();

Comment: For older C# replace "var" with a suitable object type (e.g. var loc -> Point loc).

Also change "(KeyEventHandler)((s, e)" to "delegate(object s, KeyEventArgs e)".
This has removed a "(", so lose a ")" at the end of the line

Comment: Also, I would add `e.Handled = true;` just before closing the form. Otherwise the key press will propagate to some other window afterwards!