# WebBrowser control: how to maximize it

Tags: c#, .net

I use WebBrowser in some DLL to make screenshots.

The main problem that it is not maximized sometimes and I guess it takes settigns of the Internet Explorer.

So my question is how to maximize WebBrowser control via C#?

Thank you!

```
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

            r.X = cropToRectangle.X;
            r.Y = cropToRectangle.Y;
            r.Width = cropToRectangle.Width;
            r.Height = cropToRectangle.Height;

            Point p = new Point();
            p.X = scrollTo.X;
            p.Y = scrollTo.Y;

            var sb = Math.Max(SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight);

            var size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);

            using (var form =
                new FocuslessForm
                {
                    Width = size.Width + sb,
                    Height = size.Height + sb,
                    Padding = new Padding(0),
                    Margin = new Padding(0),
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
                    Opacity = 0,
                    TabStop = false,
                    ShowInTaskbar = false
                })
            {
                var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser
                    {

                        Padding = new Padding(0),
                        Margin = new Padding(0),
                        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                        Url = url,
                        TabStop = false
                    };
                form.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);

                var finished = false;

                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate 
                {
                    webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(p); 
                    finished = true; 
                };

                form.Show();

                while (!finished)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

                image = CaptureBrowserScreenshot(webBrowser1, r);
                form.Close();
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create a fullscreen view of a group of controls, that belongs to a tabpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621443/how-create-a-fullscreen-view-of-a-group-of-controls-that-belongs-to-a-tabpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the WebBrowser is a control that is embedded into your own program's window; it doesn't launch IE as a separate process (though it does hook into IE for the renderer and other critical code). So, the control's location and size is dependent on where you embed it.

I see you are fill-docking the control to the form. This is a good first step. Now, you must make sure the WebBrowser control is being added to the Controls hierarchy of the Form (so it'll show up), and then you must maximize that Form. The way to do this is to set the WindowState property of the Form to WindowState.Maximized.

Comment: Thanks! Could u have a look at my updated code and what do I am missing there, please? Oh! I guess this WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized ??

Comment: When initializing the properties of your new FocuslessForm, set the WindowState to FormWindowState.Maximized. Should be all you need. One more thing; Application.DoEvents is generally regarded as evil. Instead, consider putting the code to capture the screenshot and close the form into the event handler for DocumentCompleted. It'll do much the same thing, but without manually triggering a call to process other Windows messages (which can cause errors relating to "non-atomic operations"; you're telling your program to run more handlers, which may expect all other handlers to be finished).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Form `resize` event, when form is maximize, i set web browser size to form size.

It worked well in my app, I share for whom concern.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Size = this.Size;
}
```