# .net win form keeps updating despite deactivated redraw.

Tags: .net, winforms, drawing, refresh, block

I need some help on this.
I want to set certain win form attributes (size/location/..) without windows automatically applying those changes on the screen.

I tried WM_SETREDRAW on the form, I skipped all messages in the WndProc of the form during the changes, nothing works. The window is adjusted automatically by the system.

Background: We need a fullscreen toggle for our application. The problem is that the user can set the window to maximized state before switching to fullscreen.

So the transition can be:
Normal -> Maximized -> Fullscreen (is WindowState Normal (BorderStyle none, max size))

According to this transition: When leaving the fullscreen mode, the application has to switch back to the maximized state. A restore should then switch the application back to the first location and size. To make the control buttons (maximize/restore) work correctly I have to go the following way when switching from fullscreen back to maximized:

1. Set the location and size to the "first" values. (As they were in normal state)
2. Set the application to maximized

Then the restore button works perfectly, but you can see that windows draws the application in step 1 and then again in step 2. You can see the windows desktop during step 1 and 2 because the window is actually resized.

Now I need a way to somehow set the values (so that the internals work correctly) but prevent windows from drawing the application until step 2.

This "deactivation" would help during the fullscreen transition also, because you can see the Panels resizing until the application covers the whole screen. Not good at all.

Any idea would be great.

Comment: This is best done by using *two* windows.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621443/how-create-a-fullscreen-view-of-a-group-of-controls-that-belongs-to-a-tabpage/4622593#4622593

Comment: That worked! We had used the WndProc to fake the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and created a custom restore functionality. The "two windows" approach is much simpler. Thanks. One more thing: How can the "flickering" be avoided when going fullscreen? Our "main" panel contains a lot of stuff (e.g. Infragistics Dockmanager with tabs) So you see a flashing when all those panels are resized.